# A function that will turn a double into a fraction

Tags: c

This is the code I had before:

```
char fractionCalculator(long double interest)
{
    char multiples_of_one_eighth[7] =  { 1 / 8, 1 / 4, 3 / 8, 1 / 2, 5 / 8, 3 / 4, 7 / 8 };

    char Return;
    char * returnValue;

  if (interest - trunc(interest) < 0.0625)
  {
    Return = '\0';
  }
  else if (interest - trunc(interest) < 0.1875)
  {
    Return = multiples_of_one_eighth[1];
  }
  else if (interest - trunc(interest) < 0.3125)
  {
    Return = multiples_of_one_eighth[2];
  }
  else if (interest - trunc(interest) < 0.4375)
  {
    Return = multiples_of_one_eighth[3];
  }
  else if (interest - trunc(interest) < 0.5625)
  {
    Return = multiples_of_one_eighth[4];
  }
  else if (interest - trunc(interest) < 0.6875)
  {
    Return = multiples_of_one_eighth[1];
  }
  else if (interest - trunc(interest) < 0.8125)
  {
    Return = multiples_of_one_eighth[1];
  }

}
```

It doesn't even run. When I made it I was thinking that the fraction would have to display as an array of chars, but I'm guessing I did that terribly wrong. I believe the reason it won't run is something to do with the output and input of the function? I've been working at this for hours and still can't figure it out. Thanks to anyone that can help!

Comment: What do you mean by "mixed number"?  That is not a valid data-type in C.  How do you think values like '1 / 8' can meaningfully fit into a `char`?

Comment: What is a "mixed number"? And what do you mean by "doesn't even run". What is the exact behaviour? Please provide a [mcve] and include the input, expected output/behaviour and actual output/behaviour.

Comment: Turn on warnings, with most compilers it's `-Wall`. It will point out a lot of problems.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is a function that takes a number and rounds it to the nearest eighth. Like 0.26 would return `"1/4"`.

The main problem is you can't store the string representation of a fraction (ie. the string `"1/4"`, not the number 1/4) in a single `char`. `char` stores a single 1 byte character. `1/8` is a mathematical formula to return a number. `"1/8"` is a 4 character string, that gets stored in a `char *`, a pointer to some memory that contains characters. You want that last one. So you're returning a `char *`.

You could return a Unicode fraction like ½ but that rapidly gets complicated.

---

Then there's all that `interest - trunc(interest)` that does nothing.

First, `trunc` takes a `double`, but `interest` is a `long double`. It returns a `double` but then subtracts it from a `long double` losing precision. Compiler warnings will tell you about things like that, turn them on with `-Wall`. You'd need to use `truncl`. It's not a big deal, it won't overtly break the code, but it will lose some of the precision of `long double`.

But you don't need to use `truncl` at all. `truncl(0.1)` is `0.0`. `truncl(0.9)` is `0.0`. All `interest - trunc(interest)` is doing, in your range, is `interest - 0`. So get rid of it.

---

There's also no need for the `Return` variable, for such a simple function you can just return immediately. You may have been told something like "there should only ever be one return from a function" which is outdated advice from a thing called [Structured Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming). It's supposed to make things simpler, but if followed too strictly it leads to complexity.

You still shouldn't return willy-nilly. For such a small function it really doesn't matter. Here we can use multiple returns for a thing called [early exit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming#Early_exit) where rather than storing a value to be returned at the end of a loop or if/else chain, we can return immediately. Makes the code simpler.

---

There's also no need for the `multiples_of_one_eighth` array. That would be useful if we could reference the fractions by array index, like:

```
int index = ...some calculation involving interest...
return multiples_of_one_eight[index];
```

But since we have to hard code each index into the if/else anyway, might as well remove some complexity and hard code the number. Then it's very easy to see mistakes. Like:

```
  else if (interest - trunc(interest) < 0.1875)
  {
    Return = multiples_of_one_eighth[1];
  }
```

You're returning `multiples_of_one_eighth[1]` but that's `1/4`. I'm pretty sure you meant `1/8`.

Put it all together and we get something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *fractionCalculator(long double interest)
{
    if (interest < 0.0625) {
        return "0";
    }
    else if (interest < 0.1875) {
        return "1/8";
    }
    else if (interest < 0.3125) {
        return "1/4";
    }
    else if (interest < 0.4375) {
        return "3/8";
    }
    else if (interest < 0.5625) {
        return "1/2";
    }
    else if (interest < 0.6875) {
        return "5/8";
    }
    else if (interest < 0.8125) {
        return "3/4";
    }
    else {
        return "1";
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("%s\n", fractionCalculator(0.8));
}
```

Note that this returns constant strings that cannot be modified, so they are declared `const char *`.

Also note that the math is a bit wrong, I basically copied what you had, so I'll leave that to you to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Check your 'multiples_of_one_eighth' array in a debugger. You will find that they are all zero, because you are asking the compiler to perform divisions like (1/8) in integer space. If I understand your desirement correctly, you probably want that to be an array of char* (c-strings), surrounded with double-quotes for each entry. Then, change your return type to char* as well.